# How to intersect between a view and a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, view, inner-join, intersect

I've a view and a table. I'm inserting data into table on the basis of that view. I want that view to eliminate same data that is already inserted into table.

This is the view which is named view_1.

```
CREATE VIEW view_1 AS
SELECT 
    y.employee_registration_id,
    x.employee_first_name,
    x.employee_last_name,
    x.employee_email,
    y.employee_current_salary_amount,
    (SELECT 
            x.salary_of_year_month_YearMonth
        FROM
            salary_of_years_months x
                LEFT JOIN
            status_salary_of_years_months y ON x.salary_of_year_month_id = y.salary_of_year_month_id
        WHERE
            y.year_month_status = 'Ongoing') AS salary_of_year_month_YearMonth,
    (SELECT 
            CONCAT(MONTHNAME(x.salary_of_year_month_YearMonth),
                        '-',
                        YEAR(x.salary_of_year_month_YearMonth))
        FROM
            salary_of_years_months x
                LEFT JOIN
            status_salary_of_years_months y ON x.salary_of_year_month_id = y.salary_of_year_month_id
        WHERE
            y.year_month_status = 'Ongoing') AS salary_of_year_month_YearMonth_MonthYear
FROM
    basic_info_employees x
        LEFT JOIN
    current_salary_employees y ON x.employee_registration_id = y.employee_registration_id
WHERE
    y.employee_current_salary_amount > 0;
```

This is the table.

```
 CREATE TABLE `salary_tracker_employees` (
serial_no INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
employee_registration_id INT(4),
employee_first_name VARCHAR(30),
employee_last_name VARCHAR(30),
employee_email VARCHAR(30),
salary_of_year_month_YearMonth VARCHAR(50),
employee_current_salary_amount DOUBLE(8 , 2 ),
PRIMARY KEY (serial_no),
UNIQUE (employee_registration_id , salary_of_year_month_YearMonth)
);
```

I want to get a view that will intersect the between view_1 and salary_tracker_employees.

Comment: In MySQL, views have extremely limited access to indexes. For this reason, I really wouldn't bother with them at all.

Comment: Completely agree, have made a temporary solution on this though.